# Application lauching problem

Tags: plugins

i have installed scrapy in ubuntu 14.02.2, but i cannot see that software in "Search your computer and online source" where will be the application normally keep?

Comment: So which version you installed and where from  ? http://scrapy.org/download/ ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find out the location of the application or package you installed you can use **locate** or **which** commands in the terminal.

**which scrapy**

If you want to check an application/ package is installed on your computer or not or want to upgrade of remove it i'd suggest you to use Synaptic package manager.

Comment: cannot see in synaptic package manager also

Comment: if its not visible in synaptic then i guess its not installed

Comment: it is installed showing in ubuntu software centre

Comment: so what else do you need? please elaborate your query

Comment: i cannot launch that application, i cant see where it is for running

Comment: how did you install it? provide a link if you followed

Comment: i have installed 2 applications for web scraping one is 

"sudo apt-get install libweb-scraper-perl " via terminal

& another one  (Scrapy) is installed through synaptic package manager

Comment: sudo scrapy startproject project_name

Comment: apply in terminal?

Comment: yes write this in terminal

Comment: a file launched in home folder

Comment: but i dnt know how this working :(

Comment: dude, the rest is related to scrapy, follow its tutorial to learn more. I dont know about scrapy and have never used it.

Answer (score 0):

I've followed the steps listed on http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/ubuntu.html , which is the link you go to by clicking "Ubuntu Package" on http://scrapy.org/download/

After running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install scrapy-0.24` , I can run scrappy in terminal, and `which scrappy` returns `/usr/bin/scrappy`. Thus `/usr/bin` is the directory you're looking for. If you need to find an application in future, you should look into `/bin`, `/usr/bin` , or `/sbin` directories, with user-installed applications located in obviously in `/usr/bin`